# POST not working with jQuery and Express

Tags: jquery, node.js, express

I've done some research but can't find anyone who's having the same problem as me.

I'm trying to send a POST request via jQuery to my Express server. My code:

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/', 
    type: 'POST', 
    contentType: 'application/json', 
    data: JSON.stringify(data);
);
```

index.js:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'crushedit' });
});

router.post('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('testing post');
});
```

The GET function works just fine. In my console, I can see /something/ is happening with the POST:

```
POST / 200 0.982 ms - 14711
```

but the page stays the same, and I never see 'testing post'. I also set up my jQuery to alert me with the data before it sends the request, and all that is working fine.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ajax calls (whether they are GET or POST) don't change the currently displayed page in the browser.  They return a response to your Javascript which your Javascript has to decide what to do with.  If you do `$.ajax(...).then(response => console.log(response));`, then you will see the response.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/', 
    type: 'POST', 
    contentType: 'application/json', 
    data: JSON.stringify(data);
}).done(function(ret) {
    console.log(ret);
});
```